# .net portal required for front end development?

Tags: frontend

this maybe a naive question but i thought i should ask this. so i saw a front end developer job ad and the requirements were like this:

[image]

I googled .net portal but what shows is .net framework which to my understanding(correct me if i am wrong) is mainly used for c# programming language.

my question is, what is a .net portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guess they mean .NET Framework.
I have not come across .NET portal yet during my years of programming.